# How to call a PHP function from JS that is invoked when clicking a link?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yui

I have this test page:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/uncancel_hike.php?hike_id=30

When clicking "yes" I am able to get the JavaScript function invoked named uncancelHike, but I don't really know how to call the PHP function.

I do import a php script with a function named uncancelHike() but I am not certain how to call it from that Javascript.

I do use YUI in the code, but not sure if I should be using it here, or this is something much simpler.

Comment: possible duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of [how to call php function in JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761448/how-to-call-php-function-in-js)

Comment: You are a 1000+ rep user. You should know how to search for answers before posting your question. There are **one million** duplicates.

Comment: 1000 rep from 239 questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AJAX here, this tutorial should helpful for you:

[Beginning AJAX Using The YUI Library](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/05/beginning-ajax-using-the-yui-library/)

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to avoid using AJAX.  Oh well, guess not :)

Comment: You can avoid using AJAX...just use a regular HTTP Get request, ex `http://mywebsite/confirmation?answer=yes` or something like any other page.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is not the answer of every thing :D

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['but1'])){
        t1();
    }elseif(isset($_POST['but2'])){
        t2();
    }


    function t1()
    {
       echo "The t1 function is called.";
    }
    function t2()
    {
       echo "The t2 function is called.";
    }

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Click1" name="but1">
<input type="submit" value="Click2" name="but2">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```